# ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class could not be converted to string - Caused by dropdown menu but why?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have the following code, which retrieves the page slugs from the database which are needed to then create a related sub page:

```
        $builder->add('subtocontentoptions', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'ShoutAdminBundle:Content',
            'property' => 'slug',
            'query_builder' => function($repository) { 
                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->where('p.mainpage = :main')
                ->setParameter('main', '1')
                ->orderBy('p.created', 'ASC');
            }
        ));
```

The code works, as it displays a drop down menu of all the parent pages I have. However, when I go to save the data to the database, I am given the following error:

> ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Shout\AdminBundle\Entity\Content could not be converted to string in
>   C:\wamp\www\vendor\doctrine-dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php line
>   131

I have checked the contents of the Content entity file, and here is the variable being declared:

```
/**
 * @var integer $subtocontentoptions
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="SubToContentOptions", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $subtocontentoptions;
```

And lower down the Content entity file:

```
/**
 * Set subtocontentoptions
 *
 * @param integer $subtocontentoptions
 */
public function setSubtocontentoptions($subtocontentoptions)
{
    $this->subtocontentoptions = $subtocontentoptions;
}

/**
 * Get subtocontentoptions
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getSubtocontentoptions()
{
    return $this->subtocontentoptions;
}
```

The rest of the code does work, once this drop down has been taken out. I'm not sure why the drop down is causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of the options in the dropdown? Is it according to the int value in the table?

Comment: Yeah it uses the Int (ID) field of the table. I'm trying to change this so it uses a different value.

Comment: try making `subtocontentoptions` protected instead of private

Comment: Also look up this bug: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1341 Do you have multi-table update here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Was having the same issue with a sf2/doctrine2 project, implementing the `__toString` method resolved this issue for me :

```
public function __toString()
{
    return strval($this->id);
}
```

Comment: if foreign key is null, then this gives error. not sure why.